# MySQL - Got an error writing communication packets

Tags: php, mysql, communication, packets

since I use my new dev server, I get this message at event log:

> Aborted connection 5 to db: 'database_name' user: 'user_name' host: 'localhost' (Got an error **writing** communication packets)For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com.

and this:

> Aborted connection 12 to db: 'database_name' user: 'user_name' host: 'localhost' (Got an error **reading** communication packets)For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com.

I've already search for solution, but all recommendations has not work. I'm using an api to sync data between iPad and MySQL server. Same api code works on live server very well, but on my dev server doesn't. I've try to use the my.ini from live server, but I still to get this error. The error comes approximal between 95 and 113 seconds after sync did start.

Here are my my.ini settings:

```
[client]
port=3306
[mysql]
no-beep
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7\Data
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="WIN2K16.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="WIN2K16-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="WIN2K16.err"
server-id=1
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"
max_connections=250
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=669M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=2G
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=17
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=256M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
query_cache_type=0
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
net_read_timeout = 60
max_execution_time = 3000
```

I hope some one can help me...

Thanks.

Comment: This basically means that the connection to the client broke down. It can have a lot of reasons, and it's impossible for us to diagnose this. It can be anything from faulty network devices/cables/(firewall)settings to errors in your code. I would try to log as much as possible (enable server logs, add logging to your apps, use network logging (e.g. wireshark)) to identify what is happening right before the connection breaks down. Also dba.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: thanks for your advice.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I'm getting this too. The only issue is that the Web server and the DB server are on the same server, therefore ruling out networking.